# Identityserver and asp.net identity in multitenant spa application and authorisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a spa application with a .net core 2 api. I would like to use identityserver 4 so that in future i can also provide a sso solution and allow access to my other api/applications. I have a database that contains the all user information (along with tenant information) for all tenants that identityserver4 will connect with. Each tenant has their own database for the spa application.

Should the api access token i get from identityserver contain role information in the claims and if so where are the roles set up(on the same database as the users or in the tenant specific databases?  Im not sure on how to then know that those roles are for which api. for example if i request the api1 scope can i get back a list of roles for that user that are just for that scope and if i request api2 scope get back a different list of roles for that user etc.

The documentation on identityserver and the docs on microsoft appear to me to contradict the way to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally role based authentication is getting phased out when oidc/oauth2 is in place because of the exact conflict that you are describing. Unless all of your web applications/api's will be respecting the central roles that you would define in your asp.net identity - then there is little to no benefit including them in the access token.

If you plan to have central role system that your other applications will respect and base their authorisation on - then I'd recommend setting the asp.net identity with Identity Server 4 in a single database, creating an Identity Resource for "roles" and including the user specific roles as a claim in the token when the "roles" scope is requested by the client.

Comment: phased out and replaced with what?

Comment: @JimmyShoe Scope based, so the allowed scopes define what the client is allowed to access.

Comment: i don't think that will work for me. Ive just been looking at PolicyServer.io have you any insight into that or alternatively what about just prepending the api name to roles eg api1.Admin, api2.Admin. That would work too wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have looked at the PolicyServer then take a look at their video. They describe a pitfall of where the authorisation concerns leek into the authentication layer. This is exactly where you seem to be heading. You are trying to make identity server to perform authorisation for you when actually it is primarily designed for providing delegated authentication mechanism. If your api scopes are getting out of hand in terms of complexity (aka you have 5+ scopes per api resource) then you should rethink and handle that with something like PolicyServer.